# Why does padding affect the width of a slider?

Tags: css, width, padding

```css
#slider1 {
  -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100px;
}

#slider2 {
  -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" orient="vertical" id="slider1" />
<input type="range" orient="vertical" id="slider2" />
```

In `slider2`, I have added padding `0 50px`, and that is the only difference between `slider1` and `slider2` but it seems like width of `slider2` has also changed. Why does this happen? Is there a way to stop it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be browser-specific, with the effect as described in e.g. Chrome but not in other browsers. It might be worth avoiding simply because of that inconsistency. Using `margin` instead of `padding` creates the space on either side of the slider, without affecting the way it looks:

```css
#slider1 {
  -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100px;
}

#slider2 {
  -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" orient="vertical" id="slider1" />
<input type="range" orient="vertical" id="slider2" />
```